# Change the overlaying order of lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
pl_data <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1, 2), times = 3), y = c(0, 1, 1, 0, .7, .7), col = rep(c("r", "b", "g"), each = 2))
ggplot(pl_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = col)) +
  geom_line(size = 3)
```

[image: Output picture]

**How can I change the plotting order, so that the red line 
is plotted above the other two?**

The background therefore is that I have plots with very similar
lines, and want to see specific lines in the foreground.

I suppose something along the lines of this answer [order of stacked bars in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433807/order-of-stacked-bars-in-ggplot) would work. It makes the color column to factors and changes their order, but I would prefer to change
this directly in a line of the ggplot call.

I also tried changing the legend order with `scale_color_discrete(breaks=c("r", "g", "b"))`),
but that does not effect the plotting order either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So actually the last level of `col` is on the top. So you need to change the order of the factor and reverse the colors as red is automatically mapped to the first level (used standard colors to illustrate the problem):

```
pl_data$col <- factor(pl_data$col, c("r", "g", "b"))
ggplot(pl_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = col)) +
    geom_line(size = 3) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c(r = "blue", g = "green", b = "red"))

## with standard colors of ggplot2, function taken from:
## http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette

ggplotColours <- function(n = 6, h = c(0, 360) + 15) {
  if ((diff(h) %% 360) < 1) h[2] <- h[2] - 360/n
  hcl(h = (seq(h[1], h[2], length = n)), c = 100, l = 65)
}
pal <- setNames(ggplotColours(3), c("b", "g", "r"))
ggplot(pl_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = col)) +
    geom_line(size = 3) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = pal, breaks = c("b", "g", "r"))
```

[image]

Comment: Got me a bit confused because of the different colors in our examples, but works nicely now! I guess I have to incorporate factors into my ggplot routine.

Comment: Ah sorry, just red `r` `g` and `b` and assumed that this fits witht the colors. Will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again, works now also in my applied example. To clarify what I meant before by my first confusion: Although the method does work, it looks as if you would have only changed the colors between the red and the blue line, as the same line is on top in both our plots. (I just should not have given my lines the names r, b, g, which do not match with their automatic colors.)

Comment: @thotal Thanks, now its perfect.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(1, 2), times = 3), 
  y = c(0, 1, 1, 0, .7, .7), 
  col = rep(c("r", "b", "g"), each = 2))

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df[3:4,], aes(x = x, y = y), color = 'blue', size = 3) +
  geom_line(data = df[5:6,], aes(x = x, y = y), color = 'green', size = 3) +
  geom_line(data = df[1:2,], aes(x = x, y = y), color = 'red', size = 3)
```

Comment: Is in my opinion good as a backup, which I also use sometimes.. But it just does not work in the automatic ggplot way, especially if your dataframe is in long format.