# ggplot strange ordering of stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am attempting to create a diverging stacked bar like [here](http://rnotr.com/likert/ggplot/barometer/likert-plots/), and am experiencing a similar issue to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433807/order-of-stacked-bars-in-ggplot). My approach is slightly different though as I am managing it all via a single dataset, rather than two and my colours are independent of my data.

Reprex as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
x <- tribble(
  ~response, ~count,
  0,         -27,
  1,          -9,
  2,         -41,
  3,         -43,
  4,         -58,
  5,        -120,
  5,         120,
  6,         233,
  7,         379,
  8,         388,
  9,         145,
  10,         61
) %>% 
  mutate(response = factor(response))

ggplot(x, aes(x = 1, y = count, fill = response)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu") +
  coord_flip()
```

This gives me an image like this:[image]

The issue is to do with the ordering of the stacked data on the right hand side of the zero where they stacking appears to be in descending order. Any thoughts on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated (expected ordering would be 0-10, not 0-5,10-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tough one! I played with ordering and it seems that `geom_bar` and `geom_col` don't like it when you combine positive and negative values in the common same order. So I divided your data inside the dataframe for positive and negative values, generated colors for every response value and used two geoms for positive and negative values separately:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
x <- tribble(
  ~response, ~count,
  0,         -27,
  1,          -9,
  2,         -41,
  3,         -43,
  4,         -58,
  5,        -120,
  5,         120,
  6,         233,
  7,         379,
  8,         388,
  9,         145,
  10,         61
) %>% 
  # Get absolute values and add dummy to distuingish positive and negative values
  mutate(subzero = count < 0,
         count = abs(count))

# Generate variable with colors from ColorBrewer for every response level (ugly but works)
colors <- brewer.pal(length(unique(x$response)),"RdBu")
x$colors <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
  x$colors[i] <- colors[x$response[i]+1]
}


ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = x[x$subzero==T,], aes(x = "", y = -count, fill = reorder(colors, response)), position="stack", stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(data = x[x$subzero==F,], aes(x = "", y = count, fill = reorder(colors, -response)), position="stack", stat="identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color =c("black")) +
  scale_fill_identity("Response", labels = unique(x$response), breaks=unique(x$colors), guide="legend") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y="",x="") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1400,1400,200), limits=c(-1400,1400))
```

UPD: made Y-scale balanced so it look more clear
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although not intuitive (for me), use:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = 1, y = order(count), fill = response)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu",direction=1) +
  coord_flip()
```

It takes into account the ordering based on response (rather than order(response))

Comment: It's a tricky one, because ultimately this should be similar to a likert scale ordering 0:10, left to right. The reason there are 2 records for 5 is because I want half to be either side of the 'midpoint' of the chart. This ordering does't quite fit the purpose.

Comment: Ah yes it is, noticed afterwards the order is reversed (relative to the legend).    Also, the values represent the ordered values (not the actual counts) making this a suboptimal answer :) Alternatively you can order the variables according to count, create a manual scale including `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11,"RdBu")` (repeating 5) and attach it your df. This can be used as input to `scale_fill_manual`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position_stack(reverse=TRUE)`:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = 1, y = count, fill = response)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse=TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Still doesn't quite work as the red ends up in the middle instead of the blue.